# Is there a git implementation that runs on top of couchdb?

Tags: git, couchdb

I've seen this old (defunct) bit of news here: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=573699 speaking about an implementation of couchdb using git and bash. I wonder, has anyone tried doing the reverse - implementing git on top of couchdb?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "implement git"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](http://rubydoc.info/github/ddollar/git-db/master/file/README.rdoc).  I used it a long time ago and it worked, but was lacking much optimization.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean an implementation where the data of a Git repository is stored in a database rather than in filesystem, then there is some work done by Shawn Pearce in JGit to achieve this. As far as i know, an integration for CouchDB isn't implemented yet, but there is an implementation for DHT like Apache HBase and Apache Cassandra (https://github.com/spearce/jgit_hbase, https://github.com/spearce/jgit_cassandra)

Answer (score 2):

Implementing git or mercurial on top of a distributed data store such as CouchDB, HBase, or bigtable is non-trivial. As far as I know there's been no implementation for git-on-CouchDB; however, if you're interested in implementing one, I would recommend checking out the Google presentation on running [mercurial on bigtable](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/MercurialBigTable.html); many of the same techniques ought to apply.